# How can I serve multiple sub-domains using a single Elastic IP Address in AWS using Route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, network-programming, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

I have a single Elastic IP address on AWS and I want to use that IP address to route traffic to multiple distinct EC2 instances based on the sub-domain. Basically, in the same manner as virtual hosts in an Apache httpd server. For example:

- example.com - ELB: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
- test.example.com points to EC2 Instance ID 1
- build.example.com point to EC2 Instance ID 2

All traffic for each of the domains would go to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and then based on the sub-domain name Route 53 would send traffic to the correct instance.

I've been through the documentation for Route 53 and I can't see how this is done. I also looked at Amazon ELB but was unsure if that would work.

Does anyone know how to set this up just using the AWS tools (Route 53 and/or ELB)? I'd rather not have to script it or use a reverse proxy if I can avoid it.

Any ideas or help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: An Elastic IP address can only be associated with a single EC2 instance. So if you have 2 distinct EC2 instances that you need to redirect subdomains to, then you'll need 2 Elastic IP addresses.

Comment: Could I assign the Elastic IP to the domain or an Internet facing ELB and then get the traffic routed internally in AWS via the instances id or private IP?

Comment: Not using ELB. You may be able to do that using nginx, HAProxy or another load balancer.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I was hoping not to have to go done that route but if looks like that may be the only solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need an elastic ip for each server. Each server already comes with an IP, so you can use that (if you actually want to address servers by ip address) - but what you likely should be doing is setting up a cname on your domain for each server, and then addressing the server's by the dns name, not by the ip address.

i.e.:

```
server1.example.com
server2.example.com
server3.example.com
```

etc

You don't *need* to use any EIP's.

Maybe you could explain better why you think all the traffic needs to go thru a single IP address?

*I can't say for sure why AWS limits you to just 5 EIPs, but I am pretty sure its because if you find out you need hundreds of EIP's then you are probably doing it wrong - and forcing you to request more than 5 gives them the ability to open up a discussion with you and help you do it a better way.*

Comment: that s true indeed, depending on the use case. Though it is worth noting that it is not recommended to record aliases on non elastic IPs: this is generally a bad practice as any change of this IP (e.g stop/start of your machine) could cause a downtime of your site while the new dns value is getting propagated. afaik the limits at AWS protect the users from bad practices (as you say), from having a bill increasing of 10k $ in 10 minutes in case you get hacked or missbehave, and also help AWS to manage its resources

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The reason I was looking to route all the traffic through a single Elastic IP address was so that I wouldn't have to ask for lots of extra EIPs from Amazon, because as you say, if I have to do that then the chances are I doing it wrong.  

And the reason I was looking to link to the instance ID (probably not possible) was so that if the server is restarted and the instance gets a new public IP and/or public DNS it will still be reachable without a manual intervention from myself.

Comment: You can add a little script to your bootstrap process that updates the route53 record for the node with the correct ip address if you need to. It will take a few minutes for the dns to propagate but unless you are restarting your instances a lot, it shouldn't matter that much.

Comment: Thanks for that. That sounds like a good solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need 1 Elastic IP address for each distinct EC2 instance that you want to redirect traffic to.

1. Create your CNAME or ALIAS record for example.com and point it to your ELB.
2. For each distinct EC2 instance that you need a sub-domain for, do the following:

   1. Allocate an Elastic IP address.
   2. Assign that Elastic IP address to the EC2 instance.
   3. Create an A record in Route 53 pointing subdomain.example.com to that Elastic IP address.

Note: Since your EC2 instances need to be accessed directly, they will need to reside inside a public subnet.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I am trying to set this up so that I don't have to go back to Amazon for a new Elastic IP address (initial limit of 5 Elastic IP addresses) every time I need to add a new server. So am I right in thinking that you are saying that if I have 100 unique servers. then I need 100 unique Elastic IP addresses from Amazon for them to be publicly accessible?

Comment: Elastic IP addresses are only required if you want your EC2 instance's IP address to be consistent. If you just need public access, then the auto-assigned public IP address will work too. However, this IP will change if the instance is stopped and restarted. Using non-Elastic IP addresses should be reserved for internal use only. (eg. dev / test servers).